# Preferences resetting in Snow Leopard

Tags: snow-leopard, preferences, shutdown

Recently my Mac has been exhibiting two strange behaviours:

1. Preferences for Safari and Windowshade return to their defaults on their own every few days.
2. On occasions, when I select **shut down**, the computer does a **reboot** instead.

What can cause these?

- Mac Pro 2012, 6 cores 3.33 Ghz
- OS X 10.6.8 (no intentions to move to Mavericks)
- OS X on SSD, user folder on HDD

Comment: outch....the shut down and reboot might be a indication of upcoming problem, so restore your OS X 10.6.8 (assuming you have a back up just in case)